# Problem with signature sent to Safe API POST request

Tags: typescript, next.js, gnosis-safe

A loom video of the problem faced:
https://www.loom.com/share/4a054656f4bb4c329983394600058a01?sid=6de4f0c4-039e-4f45-9132-584f19cec13b

I create a signer from my Metamask Private Key and then create a signature from it like this:

```
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY as string, provider)
const safeInstance = new ethers.Contract(safeAddress, safeAbi, signer)
const safeTrxHash = await safeInstance.getTransactionHash(
      trxInput.to,
      trxInput.value,
      trxInput.data,
      trxInput.operation,
      trxInput.safeTxGas,
      trxInput.baseGas,
      trxInput.gasPrice,
      trxInput.gasToken,
      trxInput.refundReceiver,
      trxInput.nonce,
    )

const signature = (await signer.signMessage(safeTrxHash))
      .replace(/1b$/, '1f')
      .replace(/1c$/, '20')
```

The signature when passed onto the API route https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0x493132b20De7b3e7825238414c204f8f30b17C7D/multisig-transactions/ provides the following error:

`` data: `{"nonFieldErrors":["Signer=0x2C7DC84b0aad92978B8D2F2fc72aBd6013cF6EB4 is not an owner or delegate. Current owners=['0xE28312CF65663803d1317c1ccf261E1edEC1FF6d']. Delegates=set()"]} ``

The signer that it says I provided is unknown to me but the address which is included in the current owners is the address i am actually providing.
I was told that the error was probably due to how signature was generated.

Can anyone help me with this.

Loom Video:
https://www.loom.com/share/4a054656f4bb4c329983394600058a01?sid=6de4f0c4-039e-4f45-9132-584f19cec13b

Answer (score 1):

You should use our API kit to interact with Safe services: https://docs.safe.global/sdk-api-kit

Answer (score 0):

For ethers v5.

This is a very common problem which is overlooked multiple times.

`ethers.signMessage()` abstracts how it perceives the `message` argument.
If you pass an array like this `['0xab', '0xbc']`, ethers will perceive it as Bytes, but if you pass a hash value represented as string `0xabbc`, ethers will perceive it as string.

Hence, if you want to sign a hash using `ethers.signMessage`, you need to explicitly let ethers know by converting a hash into bytes array using `arrayify`.

To fix this problem you need to generate signature using:

```
const signature = (await signer.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(safeTrxHash)))
      .replace(/1b$/, '1f')
      .replace(/1c$/, '20')
```

Sources: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signMessage